# Параметры у элементов автозагрузки?

Tags: windows

Доброго времени суток!

Вот, исследуя реестр Windows, наткнулся на неизвестные мне по сей день элементы - параметры у ключей. Что это за параметры такие? Параметры командной строки? Нет, но что же это тогда:

[image]

Проясните, пожалуйста. Благодарю!

Comment: Параметры запуска программы!?

Comment: Это я у вас должен спросить =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это параметры командной строки. Те что argc, *argv[] или ParamCount, ParamStr.

--
К.О.

Comment: Спасибо вам.